# Find bfs tree in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, breadth-first-search

I new to Neo4j. I have a simple graph and I want to have all nodes which almost near(distance less than 5 for instance) to a single node. Also I want the path from the source to them.
This can simply done by a single bfs from the source. 
With the following cypher query :

```
    Match c=(sourceNode:Person {name:'Demi Moore'})-[relation*1..5]-(destNode)
    return c
    limit 10
```

The query returns all path with lenght<=5 from the source but the destNode  will not be distinct. so the result can have multiple path to same dest node.

With the following query:

```
    Match c=(sourceNode:Person {name:'Demi Moore'})-[relation*1..5]-(destNode)
    return distinct destnode
    limit 10
```

The query only returns the destNodes not the path. If I change the return clause to `return distinct destnode, c`  the query also will returns a row per path it finds!
I know i can get the shortest path from source to every distinct destnode If find but it has performance issue. 
The result can be found by a single bfs and I think any graph database have the tool by default, am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need:

- optional add direction of relationships;
- sort on the length of the path;
- group by destNode and collect path;
- return destNode and first path from collect.

---

```
Match (sourceNode:Person {name:'Demi Moore'})
  With sourceNode
  Match path = (sourceNode) -[:relation*1..5]-> (destNode:Person)
    With destNode, path 
      Order By Length(path) ASC
Return destNode, Head( Collect( path) ) As path
  Order By Length(path) ASC
Limit 10
```

Comment: Doesn't this query cause it to find all paths to each node?!

Comment: Not all, but only one of the shortest to each node within five steps. Is not that what you want?

Comment: That is what I want but I think Neo4j should find all pathes from the source to one node and then order them by lengh. doesn't it?!

Comment: This query finds all nodes and paths to them within five steps. Then groups (node path) at nodes, and sort ascending path length. Next to each node gathers a collection of paths and returns the first (ie, one of the shortest). And returns a pair (host, path).

Comment: This is much heavier than a single bfs I think. It consumes more memory and cpu than a single bfs.

Comment: I think I understand you. Yes, you pointed out that we are talking about the breadth-first search?

Comment: yes, exactly true, I'm comparing your approach to BFS

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
MATCH p = (:Person {name:'Demi Moore'})-[*1..5]-(destNode)
WITH destNode, COLLECT(p) AS paths
RETURN destNode, REDUCE(s = paths[0], x IN paths[1..] | CASE WHEN LENGTH(x) < LENGTH(s) THEN x ELSE s END) AS path
limit 10;
```

It uses `COLLECT` to aggregate all the paths for the same `destNode`, and then uses `REDUCE` to find *one of* the *shortest paths* to each `destNode`.

Comment: Doesn't this query cause it to find all paths to each node?!

Comment: It returns all nodes that are up to a distance of 5 from the `Demi Moore` node, with *one of* the shortest paths to each such node.

Comment: yes but it case neo4j to find all path from source node to a node, collect the pathes and then find the shortest one. I think this is much slower than a single bfs.